# How to handle context menu in WebViewRenderer?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I know I can add context menu items this way to the Xamarin.Forms custom renderer:

```
public class MyRenderer: WebViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnCreateContextMenu (Android.Views.IContextMenu menu)
    {
        base.OnCreateContextMenu (menu);
        menu.Add (Resource.String.teststring);

    }
}
```

Now, where do I specify the action for selecting that item I've added?

Comment: You've already learned how to use `override` to implement methods such as `OnCreateContextMenu`. What hinders you from trying to `override` `OnOptionsItemSelected`, which is very well documented in the Android docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#RespondingOptionsMenu) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem))?

Comment: @Cheesebaron this is a custom renderer, I will edit the question

Comment: Well make your vague question more specific and don't omit details. We are not mind readers...

Comment: I am not being superior here. I am just pointing out that your question is really vague. If you expect someone to answer your question, improve it by providing more information.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Not sure why my comment got deleted, I said: Read the title next time, please, I clearly said WebViewRenderer in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use SetOnMenuItemClickListener on the item that's been added. You can set the handler as the renderer and implement the handling method:

```
public class MyRenderer: WebViewRenderer, IMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener
{
    protected override void OnCreateContextMenu (Android.Views.IContextMenu menu)
    {
        base.OnCreateContextMenu (menu);
        var item = menu.Add (Resource.String.teststring);
        item.SetOnMenuItemClickListener (this);

    }

    public bool OnMenuItemClick (IMenuItem item)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (item.ItemId);
        return true;
    }
}
```